# Apache ActiveMQ - Transport Connection to: tcp:/ failed: java.io.EOFException /java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using following configuration for ActiveMQ:

```xml
<beans
  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <value>file:${activemq.conf}/credentials.properties</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="logQuery" class="io.fabric8.insight.log.log4j.Log4jLogQuery"
          lazy-init="false" scope="singleton"
          init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    </bean>
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="1000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>

        <persistenceAdapter>
            <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
        </persistenceAdapter>
          <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="70" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="100 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="50 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>


        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=90000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=10000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=90000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=90000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=90000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=90000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>

        <!-- destroy the spring context on shutdown to stop jetty -->
        <shutdownHooks>
            <bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" class="org.apache.activemq.hooks.SpringContextHook" />
        </shutdownHooks>

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos
        The web consoles requires by default login, you can disable this in the jetty.xml file

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
<!-- END SNIPPET: example -->
```

When I try to run on `61616` then I am getting following error constantly and ActiveMQ does not work or does not get started properly,

```
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:30:21 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP1:61040 failed: java.io.EOFException
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:30:37 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP2:61464 failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:30:37 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP3:53301 failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:30:51 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP4:51592 failed: java.io.EOFException
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:30:51 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP5:57330 failed: java.io.EOFException
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2021/09/07 17:31:05 |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://IP6:51593 failed: java.io.EOFException
```

But when I try to run it on different port other than `61616` it works fine as there are no incoming requests on that port from any source.

Can anyone help me out here what could be the possible reason for this failure?

Comment: No. Those are different IP addresses. Requests from different sources.

Comment: In what ways exactly does ActiveMQ "not work" or "not get started properly"? What kinds of processes are making network connections from those IP addresses to `61616` on the broker?

Comment: 1st question:
--> When I run it on 61616 I get the shared WARN messages in logs and when I go to browser to access activemq at IP:8161 it says CONNECTION REFUSED. But when I run it on different port other than 61616 I am able to access activemq properly.

2nd question: 
The broker is holding messages for the client to consume after they complete the handshake with the broker.The clients also posts messages onto the broker.These messages are simple jsons which hold results of business process at the respective ends.

Comment: Please post your producer and consumer code? Please note-- ActiveMQ uses multiple ports for different services by default-- the messaging clients communicate over port 61616 (and others). The web page for manually _managing_ messages and queues is on port 8161.

Comment: Are you saying that if you run the broker without using `61616` then you can use the web console running on `8161`?

Comment: Did you tried to use connection pooling from your producer? do you have an error / exception on client side? For me it could be the network connection to be terminated because e.g you tried to send more than 90000 in a non-pooled connection. Remember the 1'000 limit is here normally to prevent clients to open to much connection and increasing this is not the solution. I would suggest to keep the 1'000 limit (instead of maximumConnections=90000) and use connection pooling from the client.

Comment: I am no sure the error comes from the non-pooled connectivity but this is anyway a good practice with ActiveMQ.